# When are duplicate flags "declined"?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I flagged [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/52010/are-non-integer-oxidation-states-possible) as a duplicate of [that](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5357/are-fractional-oxidation-states-possible).

I m not asking *why* it is not considered a duplicate; I agree that it is not a duplicate.

What is strange about it, is that I have never* seen a duplicate flag being declined before. They are either "helpful" or "aged away".

**When are duplicate-flags declined?**

<sub>(Note: This refers to my 2k helpful flags on SO)</sub>

Comment: As for why a dupe flag never gets declined on SO and it ages away, that's because SO is a giant community full of bad questions.

Comment: @Rubisco I think your comment should be part of your answer, since the only way someone would think dupe-flags cant get declined is because he has been flagging only on SO.

Comment: Fermi meh, I'll keep the answer to the point. There is always some interesting discussion to be had about moderation on these communities and on SO. You can visit [this chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) or [our chemistry chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table) for a little friendly discussion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Duplicate flags do get declined when a moderator declines them. There are only two ways to dismiss a flag, marking as helpful and declining.

[Here's something from meta.SE that makes this answer look authoritative.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=declined+duplicate+flag)

Comment: Yes, I killed that flag instantly. It was at a time where I had the feeling a lot of questions were closed as duplicates because the answer of a different question would also fit, while the questions itself were significantly different.

Comment: Let us honour the flag gone from us with a moment of silence.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I think this could be much better emphasized, that 'VTC b/c duplicate' is only for when the ***question*** is a duplicate, and not the answer. It made sense when you laid it out (in chat one time, I think? maybe in a comment thread), but I hadn't thought of it that way before.